# The CASE expression with between syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I'm working on rewriting old T-SQL procedures and today I find some difficulties.

There is a long query set in variable.

```
    set @Sql='
    ....
    ....
    where ('+ case when @p_TypeOfDataZak = 1 then 'cdn.MS_VatToDate(TrN_VatYear,
 TrN_VatMouth, TrN_VatDay) between cdn.MS_CDNDateToDate('+@DateFromv+') and cdn.MS_CDNDateToDate('+@DateTov+')'
                  else 'TrN_DataMag between '+@DateFromv+' and '+@DateTov
                   end +')
    ....
    ....
    exec (@Sql);
```

Now I want to modify it to the normal query, but I got issue with using between syntax in CASE expression. It should look like this.

```
where (case when @p_TypeOfDataZak = 1 then cdn.MS_VatToDate(TrN_VatYear, TrN_VatMouth, TrN_VatDay) between cdn.MS_CDNDateToDate(@DateFromv) and cdn.MS_CDNDateToDate(@DateTov)
              else TrN_DataMag between @DateFromv and @DateTov
               end )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After her initialisation the `@Sql` variable is string containing :

if `@p_TypeOfDataZak = 1` :

```
where (
    cdn.MS_VatToDate(TrN_VatYear, TrN_VatMouth, TrN_VatDay)
    between cdn.MS_CDNDateToDate('+@DateFromv+')
    and cdn.MS_CDNDateToDate('+@DateTov+')
)
```

if `@p_TypeOfDataZak <> 1` :

```
where (
    TrN_DataMag between '+@DateFromv+' and '+@DateTov+'
)
```

If you want remove `case/when` and `dynamic` sql contruction, try this :

```
where
(
    cdn.MS_VatToDate(TrN_VatYear, TrN_VatMouth, TrN_VatDay)
    between cdn.MS_CDNDateToDate('+@DateFromv+')
    and cdn.MS_CDNDateToDate('+@DateTov+')
    and @p_TypeOfDataZak = 1
)
or
(
    TrN_DataMag between '+@DateFromv+' and '+@DateTov+'
    and @p_TypeOfDataZak <> 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using variables and `sp_execute_sql` -- especially if you are updating code!

So:

```
set @Sql='
....
....
where (' +
      case when @p_TypeOfDataZak = 1 then 
           then 'cdn.MS_VatToDate(TrN_VatYear, TrN_VatMouth, TrN_VatDay) between cdn.MS_CDNDateToDate(@DateFromv) and cdn.MS_CDNDateToDate(@DateTov)'
           else 'TrN_DataMag between @DateFromv and @DateTov
      end + ')
  ....

exec sp_executesql @Sql,
                   N'@DateTov date, @DateFromv date',
                   @DateTov=@dateTov, @DateFromv=@DateFromv
```

Comment: You misunderstood me, i want to get rid of seting querry in variable.